# Unary minus operator overload not calling move constructor

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, move-semantics

I am trying to figure out why the unary minus overload is calling a copy constructor and not a move constructor.  The addition overload does call the move constructor.

I am assuming I am passing an rvalue to the below constructor and this should call the move constructor but the below code calls the copy constructor.

```
    template<class T>
    inline _CNative<T> _CNative<T>::operator-() const &
    {
        BENCHMARK(__FUNCSIG__)
        return _CNative<T>(-m_T);
    }

Logger Output (Copy Constructor called)

Begin;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
    Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
    End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
End;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
```

I am assuming I am passing an rvalue to the below constructor and this should call the move constructor and the below code does call the move constructor

```
    template<class T>
    inline _CNative<T> _CNative<T>::operator+(const _CNative<T>& Other) const &
    {
        BENCHMARK(__FUNCSIG__)
        return _CNative<T>(m_T + Other.m_T);
    }

Logger Output (Move Constructor called)

Begin;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator +(const class _CNative<int> &) const &
    Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
    End;2;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator +(const class _CNative<int> &) const &
```

Below is the code and the logger output

Class Declaration

```
    template <class T>
    class _CNative
    {
    public:
        //Constructors
        _CNative();                             //Default 
        _CNative(const _CNative& Other);        //Copy
        _CNative(_CNative&& Other) noexcept;    //Move
        _CNative(const T& Other);               //Parameterized Copy
        _CNative(T&& Other) noexcept;           //Parameterized Move

        //Assignment Operators
        _CNative& operator=(const _CNative& Other);         //Copy
        _CNative& operator=(_CNative&& Other) noexcept;     //Move
        
        //Arithmetic Operators
        _CNative operator-() const &;
        _CNative operator-() &&;
        _CNative operator+(const _CNative<T>& Other) const &;
```

Constructor Definitions

```
    template<class T>
    inline _CNative<T>::_CNative(const T& Other) : m_T(Other)
    {
        BENCHMARK(__FUNCSIG__)
    }

    template<class T>
    inline _CNative<T>::_CNative(T&& Other) noexcept : m_T(std::move(Other))
    {
        BENCHMARK(__FUNCSIG__)
    }
```

Code

```
    int main()
    {
        CInt A = 1;
        CInt B = 1;
        CInt C = 1;
    
        C = A + B;
        C = -(-A);
    
        return 0;
    }

Logger output

Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator +(const class _CNative<int> &) const &
    Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
    End;2;_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator +(const class _CNative<int> &) const &
Begin;_CNative<int> &__cdecl _CNative<int>::operator =(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int> &__cdecl _CNative<int>::operator =(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
Begin;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
    Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
    End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
End;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
Begin;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) &&
    Begin;_CNative<int>::_CNative(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
    End;_CNative<int>::_CNative(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int> __cdecl _CNative<int>::operator -(void) &&
Begin;_CNative<int> &__cdecl _CNative<int>::operator =(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;_CNative<int> &__cdecl _CNative<int>::operator =(class _CNative<int> &&) noexcept
```

I am using MSVC Compiler.  I ran it in release to see if it changed, but the copy constructor is still called.

```
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;1;300;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;1;-660500;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;1;-583200;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator +(const class Core::_CNative<int> &) const &
    Begin;2;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
    End;2;200;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(int &&) noexcept
End;1;1100;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator +(const class Core::_CNative<int> &) const &
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> &__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator =(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;1;300;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> &__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator =(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
    Begin;2;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
    End;2;200;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(const int &)
End;1;1400;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator -(void) const &
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator -(void) &&
    Begin;2;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
    End;2;300;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::_CNative(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;1;1000;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> __cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator -(void) &&
Begin;1;0;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> &__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator =(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
End;1;300;RELEASE;WIN64;MSVC;class Core::_CNative<int> &__cdecl Core::_CNative<int>::operator =(class Core::_CNative<int> &&) noexcept
```

Comment: What does the `Benchmark` macro look like?

Comment: I am using MSVC...  Ran it in release and it didn't fix it.  It still calls the copy constructor.

Comment: BENCHMARK(x) is just Benchmark BM(x).  It just calls a class constructor with the function name as an input.  It is a macro because I need to add conditions to run it off.  It is just used mainly for debug.